# Association Rules for Text File

Tags: rapidminer

I am a student using Rapidminer, and I am doing a project using Yummly's What's Cooking dataset (https://www.kaggle.com/c/whats-cooking/data).  The dataset has 20 different cuisine types (e.g. Italian, Chinese, Indian, etc.).

Our goal is to develop a data mining model that identifies the cuisine type of future dishes by analyzing the ingredient list of the dish. We are using association rules to do so. However, I keep getting "no rules found" and have no idea why. I am thinking this has something to do with my attributes being formatted as text and not using the nominal to binominal operator, but am not sure how to fix it.

Currently my process looks like....

data -> select attributes -> FP growth -> create association rules

Can you help?

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation for the FP-Growth operator, all the attributes in the example set need to be binomial.

I'll admit--I haven't looked at the data directly because I didn't want to register an account on kaggle, so I'm not sure exactly how it's formatted,  but you would probably want to set the type of cuisine as a label and then have each of the remaining attributes represent each ingredient that is included in one or more of the recipes.  Each dish would have a 1 in the column if the ingredient is used and a 0 if it's not used.  (Depending on the original format of the data, since you mentioned it's text, you may want to check out the text processing extension, which can create an example set like what I just described.)  Then, if you convert the 0s and 1s to binomial, you should be able to use FP-Growth.